# Вычесть поочередно элементы списка из элементов другого списка

Tags: python, список

У меня два списка с одинаковым количеством элементов в каждом. Требуется произвести вычитание элементов. Ответ должен быть таким

```
summ =[0,0,1]

az = [1,2,3]
bz = [1,2,4]
summ = [j-k for k in az for j in bz]
```

Но код выше дает другой результат: вычитает из каждого каждый и в новом списке получается 9 элементов вместо трех.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from operator import sub

az = [1,2,3]
bz = [1,2,4]

sub_iter = map(sub, bz, az)
print(list(sub_iter)) # -> [0, 0, 1]
```

Но если хотите именно списковым выражением

```
[a - b for a, b in zip(bz, az)]
```

Comment: Спасибо, но возможно же это сделать без сторонних модулей?

Comment: @Kirill Это модуль стандартной библиотеки Питона. Присутствует везде.

Answer (score 4):

Вместо вашего

```
summ = [j-k for k in az for j in bz]
```

используйте

```
summ = [j-k for k, j in zip(az, bz)]
```

---

**Объяснение**:

Ваша команда делает то-же самое как

```
summ = []
for k in az:
    for j in bz:
        summ.append(j-k)
```

(1-й элемент списка `az` со всеми элементами списка `bz`, затем 2-й элемент списка `az` со всеми элементами списка `bz`, и т.д., **совсем 9 пар**).

Но вы хотите проходить оба списки *синхронно*, по первым элементам из обоих списков, затем по вторым элементам из обоих списков, и т.д. - **совсем только 3 пары**.

Для этого применяется функция `zip()`, которая из ваших 2 списков сделает что-то как *список пар соответствующих элементов*: `[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 4)]`.

Часть

```
[ ... for k, j in zip(az, bz)]
```

выбирает для `k` первый и дла `j` второй елемент из этих пар.